# Error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Não consigo encontrar o erro desse código ao salvar a imagem da webCam, sempre que clico em salvar como e digito o nome do arquivo ele me retorna com esse erro

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public DirectX.Capture.Filter Camera;
        public DirectX.Capture.Capture CaptureInfo;
        public DirectX.Capture.Filters CamContainer;
        Image capturaImagem;
        public string caminhoImagemSalva = null ;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           CamContainer = new DirectX.Capture.Filters();  
           try
           {
             int no_of_cam = CamContainer.VideoInputDevices.Count;
#pragma warning disable CS0162 // Unreachable code detected
                for (int i = 0; i < no_of_cam; i++)
#pragma warning restore CS0162 // Unreachable code detected
                {
                try
                {
                        // obtém o dispositivo de entrada do vídeo
                        Camera = CamContainer.VideoInputDevices[i];

                        // inicializa a Captura usando o dispositivo
                        CaptureInfo = new DirectX.Capture.Capture(Camera, null);

                        // Define a janela de visualização do vídeo
                        CaptureInfo.PreviewWindow = this.picWebCam;

                        // Capturando o tratamento de evento
                        CaptureInfo.FrameCaptureComplete += AtualizaImagem;

                        // Captura o frame do dispositivo
                        CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();

                        // Se o dispositivo foi encontrado e inicializado então sai sem checar o resto
                        break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    throw ex;    
                }
            }

                {
                    this.TopMost = false;
                    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
        }
     }

        public void AtualizaImagem(PictureBox frame)
        {
            try
            {
                capturaImagem = frame.Image;
                this.picImagem.Image = capturaImagem;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnCaptura_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta
                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
                Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\ssbfci\Documents\FOTOS DO FERRAMENTAL\"
            };
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

                // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
                if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
                {
                    // salva a imagem por fileStream
                    System.IO.FileStream fs =
                       (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
                    // Salva a imagem no formato certo
                    switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            this.btnSalvar.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            this.btnSalvar.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            this.btnSalvar.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                            break;
                    }

                    fs.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Designer

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.picWebCam = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.picImagem = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.btnCaptura = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnSalvar = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picWebCam)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picImagem)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // picWebCam
            // 
            this.picWebCam.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.picWebCam.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.picWebCam.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 133);
            this.picWebCam.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.picWebCam.Name = "picWebCam";
            this.picWebCam.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(715, 503);
            this.picWebCam.TabIndex = 0;
            this.picWebCam.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // picImagem
            // 
            this.picImagem.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.picImagem.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1021, 133);
            this.picImagem.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.picImagem.Name = "picImagem";
            this.picImagem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(697, 503);
            this.picImagem.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.picImagem.TabIndex = 1;
            this.picImagem.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // btnCaptura
            // 
            this.btnCaptura.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnCaptura.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(237, 668);
            this.btnCaptura.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.btnCaptura.Name = "btnCaptura";
            this.btnCaptura.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(581, 55);
            this.btnCaptura.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnCaptura.Text = "Capturar Imagem";
            this.btnCaptura.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnCaptura.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCaptura_Click);
            // 
            // btnSalvar
            // 
            this.btnSalvar.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSalvar_Click);
            this.btnSalvar.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnSalvar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1080, 668);
            this.btnSalvar.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.btnSalvar.Name = "btnSalvar";
            this.btnSalvar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(581, 55);
            this.btnSalvar.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnSalvar.Text = "Salvar Imagem";
            this.btnSalvar.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 730);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1065, 310);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.textBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(515, 29);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(893, 74);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.textBox1.Text = "CAIXA DE PEÇA SEPARADA";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1864, 1062);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSalvar);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnCaptura);
            this.Controls.Add(this.picImagem);
            this.Controls.Add(this.picWebCam);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Capturando Imagem da WebCam";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picWebCam)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picImagem)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picWebCam;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picImagem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCaptura;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSalvar;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: é provavel que `fs` esteja nulo. Tire o try catch pra ver o erro ou coloque um break point no catch e veja o stacktrace.

Comment: fiz o que você falou, ele me retorna assim `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.Image.get returned null.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está tentando salvar a imagem do botão `btnSalvar` ao invés da imagem capturada pela webcam.

troque:

```
this.btnSalvar.Image.Save(fs,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

por

```
this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

em todas as linhas dentro do switch.

> Antes do `switch`, verifique se `this.picImagem.Image` é nulo antes de continuar.

Comment: nossa muito obrigado, agora foi certinho

Comment: Um outro detalhe importante: é importante fechar o arquivo (`fs.close()`) na instrução `catch`. Senão, você não vai conseguir salvar sobre o mesmo arquivo quando ocorrer erro porque ele vai ficar alocado para outro processo.

Comment: boa @Fernando, valeu pela dica